# C++ overloading operator +

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have found a lot of tutorials/snippets online, that suggest to use an overloading of this type:

`NumeroFarlocco operator+(NumeroFarlocco n1, NumeroFarlocco n2) { ... }`

But if I put this definition in my .h file:

`NumeroFarlocco operator+(NumeroFarlocco n1, NumeroFarlocco n2);`

I have this error:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/1zy85x1e(v=vs.80).aspx

So I have figured out I have to define the overloading like this:

```
NumeroFarlocco operator+( NumeroFarlocco n2 );
```

but in the implementation I can't understand how to access the instance variables of the first element involved in the operation (the one that was n1 in my previous code), this->variable does not work, neither variable ...

Comment: Can you post your code, please? What you're describing appears to be valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to overload a binary operator:

- as a class member
- as a free operator

Both are valid in different contexts:

```
struct A
{
    A operator+ (const A& other) const;
};
```

and

```
struct A
{};
operator+(const A& first, const A& second);
```

*Note the use of `const`.*

As a member, the two objects being added are `*this` and `other`. The first is the implicit current object.

As a free operator, the two objects are the ones passed as parameters.

Comment: shouldn't the first operator (the class member) return a reference `A&` ?

Comment: @Shai no, you're thinking of `+=`. `+` returns a new object.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore "`+` returns a new object" -> "`+` _should_ return a new object".  The standard allows you to overload `operator+` and give it the semantics of `+=`; common sense and respect for your collegues doesn't.

Comment: Yes, *should* return a new object. :)

Comment: I think it is worth adding some notes on the preferred method to use.

Answer (score 1):

```
NumeroFarlocco operator+(NumeroFarlocco n1, NumeroFarlocco n2)
```

Should be an out-of-class definition, that is, a free function.

```
class NumeroFarlocco {
  // ...
};

NumeroFarlocco operator+(NumeroFarlocco n1, NumeroFarlocco n2) {
  // ...
}
```

If you using `NumeroFarlocco operator+( NumeroFarlocco n2 );` it goes inside the class definition. Yes, the `this` pointer is how you access the left-hand-side value.

Comment: You don't really need the `this` pointer though (except for some cases with templates)

Comment: And if you need to access private variables to calculate your answer, you can declare the external function a `friend` of your class.

Comment: @JackAidley If you implement `+=` with the right semantics, you don't need to access any private variables in `+`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: True, I was mentioning it for completeness more than anything else. Plus you may want to implement a separate `operator+` for efficiency's sake under some circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

Those are two different things,

The first method:

```
NumeroFarlocco operator+(NumeroFarlocco n1, NumeroFarlocco n2);
```

defines globally how to interprete the + operator.

That is it does means:

```
NumeroFarlocco n = operator+(n0,n2);
```

Where as the second one:

```
NumeroFarlocco operator+( NumeroFarlocco n2 );
```

defines how to interprete the addition of one to another.

that is:

```
NumeroFarlocco n = n0.operator+(n1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to expand somewhat on Luchian Grigore's answer.
Technically, as he says, there are two ways of defining binary
operators.  In practice, however, a certain number of
conventions are usually followed; in particular, binary objects
which return a new object (like `operator+`) are usually defined
as non members, and those which modify the left operand (like
`operator+=`) are usually defined as members.  In addition, it
is frequent to define the functions which return an object by
using those which modify an object, e.g.:

```
MyType
operator+( MyType const& lhs, MyType const& rhs )
{
    MyType results( lhs );
    results += rhs;
    return results;
}
```

In fact, I don't normally even write the functions which return
a value; I've written a base class template which defines them,
and derive from that:

```
template <typename DerivedClass>
class MathematicOperators
{
    friend DerivedClass
    operator+( DerivedClass const& lhs, DerivedClass const& rhs )
    {
        DerivedClass results( lhs );
        results += rhs;
        return results;
    }
    //  And so on for all of the binary operators...
};

class MyClass : MathematicOperators<MyClass>
{
    //  ...
    MyClass& operator+=( MyClass const& other )
    {
        //  modify *this...
        return *this;
    }
    //  ...
};
```

(Note that the friend in `MathematicOperators` is *not* to be
able to access private members of the derived class, but to be
able to define the free function inline in the class template.)

I would strongly recommend following this procedure.  It will
result in a lot less code, and will guarantee that `+` and `+=`
have the expected relationship.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you might want to read the following [tutorial](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/91-introduction-to-operator-overloading/) to learn some basic rules on how to overload operators.

Starting with your original code :

```
NumeroFarlocco operator+(NumeroFarlocco n1, NumeroFarlocco n2);
```

This is might not what you really want to declare. The way you declare operator+ is dependant on what you want to achieve.

Assuming from your question, you want to overload the binary+, so you would do it like this:

```
friend NumeroFarlocco operator+(NumeroFarlocco n1 , NumeroFarlocco n2 );
```

or alternatively as you declared above :

```
NumeroFarlocco operator+( NumeroFarlocco n2 );
```

The difference between these two declaration is that the first one is friend(free funcion) while the second one is a member function.

The first one(using friend function) means you don't call the function via object (it's like a global function), the second one means that you must call this function via object (as you normally do with member function).

Also, always remember that operator is a function.

```
NumeroFarlocco x, y, z; // suppose you have empty/default c'tor

x = y + z  is equivalent to x.operaotr=(y.operator+(z))
```

Hope it helps you,
Syndicator!